# Creating constructor that builds object from string[JAVA]

Tags: java, constructor, implementation

I want to create a constructor in the class Observation that builds an object from an text string.

```
public class Observation implements Comparable
{

    private int photoboxID;

    private long passingTime;

    private int speedKMprHour;

    private String carID;


    /**
     * Constructor for one line from a textfile.
     * @param oneLine is a string that describes an observation
     */
    public Observation(String oneLine)
    {
        photoboxID = Integer.parseInt(oneLine[0]);
    }

}
```

---

Example of textfile.
each line is set up like this:

```
photoboxID:passingTime:speedKMprHour:carID
2:1335421861264:67:AD23415
2:1335422881262:90:AD53417
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So this question is about how to parse that string?

Comment: I'd say, please go ahead and give it a go, see what you can come up with. Then if still stuck, please come on back with a more specific and answerable question based on your code attempt.

Comment: I edited the constructor with one line. See OP.

this is what i can think of, im not very skilled at java.

ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to split the oneLine and assign the values to individual properties.

```
public Observation(String oneLine)
{
        String[] splitItems = oneLine.split(":");
        this.photoboxID = Integer.valueOf(splitItems[0]);
        this.passingTime = Long.valueOf(splitItems[1]);
        this.speedKMprHour  = Integer.valueOf(splitItems[2]);
        this.carID = splitItems[4];
}
```